# Import module in React several times. Is the code executed once vs executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, module

Everything started from the need to do a configuration in a function call and figure out what happened if imported in more than one file.

I have this function

```
function.js
export function myFunction() {
  let b = Math.random();
  return b;
}
```

Two cases. Import the function directly and display it in several places. Different values are displayed.
First case

```
App.js
import myFunction from "./myFunction";
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>{myFunction()}</h3>
        <h3>{myFunction()}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Second case.

```
counter.js
import myFunction from "./myFunction";
export default myFunction(7)

App.js
import counter1 from "./counter";
import counter2 from "./counter";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>counter1</h3>
        <h3>counter2</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In this second case, the same value is displayed.

There is an article here :https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-module-import-twice/
Still could not completely explain what happens though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first scenario, there are two separate calls to `myFunction`,
that is to say two separate calls to `Math.random()` (considering its implementation).

In the second scenario, `counter1` and `counter2` refer to the same `'./counter'` module instance.
*This* instance exposes a constant (i.e.: `myFunction(7)`) which has been initialized at module instantiation:

- When the `import counter1 from './counter';` statement is read:

  - It looks if the `'./counter'` module has already been evaluated
  - As it is not the case, it evaluates the `'./counter'` module
  - At this moment, the constant `myFunction(7)` is created (let's assume it equals `0.12345`)
    and exposed as the `default` export of the `'./counter'` module instance
  - Then, in *App.js*, the `counter1` variable takes the value `0.12345`
- When the `import counter2 from './counter';` statement is read:

  - It looks if the `'./counter'` module has already been evaluated
  - As it has already been imported/evaluated with the same path,
    it returns the same & existing `'./counter'` module instance
  - It looks at its `default` export, which is `0.12345`
  - Thus, in *App.js*, the `counter2` variable also takes the value `0.12345`

That is why the same value is displayed.